# Why Blender Rendering and Previewing Wrong Colors in Video Editor?

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor

I'm quite new in Blender and I have encountered a problem while I was editing a video with Blender Video Editor. Blender makes the colors of my video worse and wrong. Before rendering the video I didn't notice that, but after rendering there was a remarkable difference between the original and rendered colors. I tried some suggestions given on the internet but they didn't work, anything didn't change in both preview and render. I will give an instance here:

[image: Blender Wrong Colors]

In the image above, in comparison to the real one, Blender rendered video has completely wrong colors. It makes my video white to gray. As I mentioned, it is not only happening in the render section, also occurs in the video preview. So while editing the video I can see the difference. When you once noticed that you cannot prevent looking for the wrong colors and it became really terrible situation for me. I have already tried to change my output settings, I tried nearly all the options about video. Also, I tried rendering it as an image in different image formats. But it still occurs and nothing is changing. Do you have any other suggestions about this problem? What are your thoughts about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I fixed the problem. As I said, I'm quite new and haven't got a comprehensive knowledge about the panels and settings in Blender.

Instead of deleting the question, I will answer it and help the other people who have encountered this problem. Let me explain how I solved it briefly:

[image: Fixed]

Under the "Render Context Tab", there is a setting called "Color Management". As a default, its "View Transform" is "Filmic", let's change it to "Standart" or "Raw". The problem will be fixed in this way.

In a nutshell, Render Context -> Color Management" -> View Transform -> Standart.